# jQuery scroll.function not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create an effect where on scroll Navigation change it css properties

Any suggestion why this code is not working? The other jQuery code works fine, thanks

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-3">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="ij-effect-15">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" data-hover="Brand">Brand</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-3">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="cool-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="cool-link" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="cool-link" href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a class="cool-link" href="#">Works</a></li>
        <li><a class="cool-link" href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a class="cool-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="collapse nav navbar-nav nav-collapse" id="nav-collapse3">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is my jquery.

```
    (function() {
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 10) {
          $(".navbar-fixed-top").css("background-color", "#f8f8f8");
        } else {
          $(".navbar-fixed-top").css("background-color", "transparent");
        }
      });
    });
  })();
```

Comment: It's working: https://jsfiddle.net/jnjaf0Lc/

Comment: You're right, but does not reflect on brackets,no idea why...